# RKRequest forcebasisauthentication unrecognized selector (property not fount)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, restkit

I just upgraded restkit to 0.10.2. I got an error in this code :

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/browse/authentication/#", address]];

RKRequest *request = [RKRequest requestWithURL:url delegate:self];
request.forceBasicAuthentication = YES;
request.username = [loginField text];
request.password = [passwordField text];
[request send];
```

Error:

```
[RKRequest setForceBasicAuthentication:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x348420
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[RKRequest setForceBasicAuthentication:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x348420'
```

I didn't change any code after upgrading restkit.
Thanks!

EDIT: Title

Comment: So apparently i've to use this instead:

`request.authenticationType = RKRequestAuthenticationTypeHTTPBasic`

However, xcode don't find "authenticationType" in my RKRequest object, while he is able to jump to declaration... I think i'm doing something wrong with restkit import but did not find it...

Help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code completion error solved by doing `Product->Hold down option button->"Clean Build Folder"` :)